# AWS Route 53 DNS Settings and changing setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns

I have been running my domain via DNS settings on Route 53. I have had to change my DNS settings back to the internet service providers DNS settings.

I deleted the DNS management in AWS and changed the DNS server settings back to the default with my host provider. However after 48 hours the DNS settings are still directing towards the AWS settings.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: I had to set up the DNS on my new ISP before I could delete the settings in Route 53. It took me a while but I thought I would share this answer so others might not face the same trouble.